# Does join combine the same column with same name and data?

Tags: sql, orm, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Im reading this [article](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/nested-queries-with-sqlalchemy-orm) by Miguel Grinberg, and on the 'The Join' part, I'm kinda confused with the result.

To sum up the part I'm concerned, he joined a query and a subquery belonging to the SAME table on the condition where its `customer_id`'s are the same

- Query selected: `id, customer_id, order_date`
- Subquery selected: `customer_id, max(order_date) AS last_order_date`

When he joined it I was expecting something like:

```
id | customer_id | order_data | customer_id | last_order_date
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

But his result was:

```
id | customer_id | order_data | last_order_date
-----------------------------------------------
```

Where is the other `customer_id` selected from the subquery?

With that I would like to confirm if my understanding is correct, a JOIN also combines two COLUMNS if it has the same NAME and VALUE.

Comment: Edit your question and show the query.

Comment: You only get the columns from the `orders` table because the main query uses `Order.query`, which returns all of the columns from just that table.

Comment: I once ran the query again but this time i restructured it using `db.session.query(Order, last_orders)` and I was able to get the other `customer_id`. And as emphasized by @GordThompson, the original query is designed only to return columns from the `Order` table. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the article uses `select *` when it should be using `select orders.*, last_orders.last_order_date` already makes me suspicious of anything else in the article.

Most databases would run the query and return two columns with `customer_id` -- as you suggest should happen.  However, there is then a problem in *accessing* both those columns in an application.  They have the same name. So, the columns might be elided in some way.

All that said, this is a rather poor example, because the query is much better written using window functions:

```
select o.*, max(order_date) over (partition by customer_id)
from orders o;
```

Comment: True that the usage of `select *` might have been the reason why I got confused. And comparing with the raw query produced by the orm version of the query, it explicitly selected only the columns from `Order` and none from the subquery table. Hence, it should instead be using the `select` that you suggested. Thank you!